# Visual code No detect my variables of WTForms Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

My visual code does not detect my variable of WTForm of Flask Forms, it was working all ok, but 2 days ago I have this problem, in this example my Flask form variable are: form.nombres.data; visual code doesn't identify these variables.

```
#DATOS
@app.route('/documento_template',methods=['GET','POST'])
def datos_personales():
    
    form=clase.Formulario()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        
        valor1=form.nombres.data    
        valor2=form.cargo.data
        valor3=form.direccion.data
        
        datos=(valor1,valor2.upper(),valor3)
        adm.registrar.informacion(datos)

    return render_template('documento_template.html',form=form)
```